# T3 Mega Menu - How to dynamically populate menu column by tag?

Tags: menu, t3-framework

I'm using T3 Mega Menu (JoomlArt Teline template).

It has a module that automatically populates mega menu columns by category.

I'd like, to, instead, assign tags to articles, and then auto-populate the mega menu column by the specified tag (i.e. if the article has the specified tag, then list in the menu column (category tag, pic and title)).

Does anyone know if there is a module available that will do this?

If yes, where can one be found?

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With T3 Mega Menu you can include a module as a menu item as follows:

- go to `Extensions -> Templates` and edit your T3 template
- click on the "Megamenu" button
- select your Main Menu or similar
- click on the menu item under which you wish to add the module
- set "Submenu" to "On" if it's not already on
- click in the box that appears
- select an appropriate module from the module list
- click on the "Save" button to save

Now all that remains to do is to find a suitable module from the Extensions directory that displays the tags, images and titles in the way you wish.

If no such module exists, you could install [Regular Labs Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer) or similar and create a Custom HTML module with custom code to create exactly what you wish.

You will likely need to style the output of the module in a similar fashion to the existing menu styling to make it fit well aesthetically.

I have used a similar strategy of adding modules to [RokNavMenu](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/roknavmenu) to display dynamic menu options based on content in the database.